# Collapse geometries with equal name using R

Tags: r, geometry, gis, raster, r-sf

Hi everyone I have a multipolygon with geometris that belong to the same entity but are separated. For example, I have 14 geometries that are all to the same district, identified with the column `name`. What I want is to create loop wherein if any two rows have the same value for `name` they are collapsed into only one geometry and row in the multipolygon.

The multipolygon is the following:

```
Avon    09  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Avon    09  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Bedfordshire    10  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Berkshire   11  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Buckinghamshire 12  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Cambridgeshire  13  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Cheshire    14  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Cleveland   15  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Cornwall and Isles of Scilly    16  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991    
Cornwall and Isles of Scilly    16  <S3: sfc_POLYGON>   1991
```

A small dput (column `year` not included) can be accessed here:
https://pastebin.com/sTcFJuds

So for example if there are more than one row with `name` == `Cornwall and Isles of Scilly` I want them and their geometries to be merged.

I tried the following:

```
#create output sf
test <- st_sf(name = 1:nrow(counties.91),
              label = 1:nrow(counties.91),
              year = 1:nrow(counties.91),
              geometry = st_sfc(lapply(1:nrow(counties.91), function(x) st_geometrycollection())))

    #create for loop
    for (i in 1:nrow(counties.91)) {
#for every row of the multipolygon
      sub <- counties.91[which(counties.91$name == counties.91$name[i]), ] 
#subset those with the same name 
        test <- st_union(counties.91[i, ], sub)
#and collapse them together
    }
```

However, this is not working. What I get out is all the last rows that have the same value for `name`, and they're not merged and all attribute columns are duplicated for each row.
Here:

```
test
<S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
1   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
2   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
3   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
4   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
5   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
6   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
7   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
8   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
9   Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
10  Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
11  Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
12  Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
13  Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
14  Northumberland  36  1991    Northumberland  36  1991    <S3: sfc_GEOMETRY>
```

If someone also has a solution with a function, also happy to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Consider `dplyr:: summarize ()` - you will find it illustrated in https://stackoverflow.com/q/66068003/7756889

Comment: uau, that's so much easier than what I was trying. and so obvious too. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of service!